# Genre Detection AI (Architecture)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

My neural network is not really learning at the moment. I am currently using the model on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nOu_CHogWw) video.

---

### Structure

```py
def get_conv_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='same',     input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    # model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    # model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(config.cat, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
    return model
```

## Dataset

- 3 genres * 170 tunes (total 510 Songs)
- each song cut for 1 random second

## Process

- 20 epochs

## Result

- around 0.9214 acc (loss 0.2074)

However, the predictions are all based on only one of the 3 genres. So almost 50% of the classification is wrong.